# My bitcoin node is down again, not binding to my home ip:8333

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin.conf

I am getting the following error;
[net:error] Unable to bind to xxx.xx.147.xxx:8333 on this computer (bind returned error Cannot assign requested address (99)). I did a restart after trying to get some docker files, don't know if that caused, but I cant figure out how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really provide anything like enough information, so what follows is inevitably guesswork.

> **`bind returned error Cannot assign requested address`**

Your PC no longer has the specified address

> **I did a restart after trying to get some docker files,**

DHCP allocated a new IP-address?

or

IPV6 not enabled in Docker

---

Possible fixes

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/55844788/477035
- alter bitcoin.conf to bind to any IPV4 address allocated to any active network interface
- DHCP reservation
- statically allocated IP-address